# FlashForge Creator Pro 3 - tlumping together

Tags: flashforge-creator, flashforge

I am trying to do 48 4 mm wide cylinders at a time 5-25 mm apart and after the first few layers are put down they all get caught up together and the machine goes around collecting them all into 1 giant ball of filament.  Any ideas?  I set the nozzle temperature to 215 °C and the platform to 65 °C.

Comment: You need to list info like what type of material you are printing, what print speed, speed for non-printing movements, etc.

Comment: Hello, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Your question is lacking detail and as such is hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading `<!--` and trailing `-->` afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem. Also add a photo of the first layer when the nozzle hasn't picked up any of the other objects, it might indicate a lack of adhesion or an extrusion problem. You also might want to avoid crossing previously printed areas.

Comment: Is tlumping a word?